# Определить размер страницы и указать в CSS

Tags: html, css

Пример: пользователь заходит на сайт и сайт определяет высоту и ширину устройства пользователя и делит в ширину div блок на 3 части.

```
.block {
   width=calc(его размер/3);
}
```

Можно ли это выполнить каким-то образом?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте относительные единицы измерения `vw` и `vh`

```
vh - Эквивалентно 1% высоты окна браузера
vw - Эквивалентно 1% ширины окна браузера
```

следовательно вам нужно

```
.block {
   width: calc(100vw / 3);
}
```